# How to fix a widget to the bottom of the screen without causing render overflow in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to achieve the effect shown on the screenshots below:

---

**First scenario:**

The green widget is fixed to the bottom. Container isn't scrollable, as the content is short enough.

[image]

---

**Second scenario:**

The green widget is pushed to the bottom. The container is scrollable, as the content is too long to fit in the viewport.

[image]

---

The problem is, that since technically `SingleChildScrollView's` height is infinite, it's impossible to push the green widget to the end of the viewport.

So, what needs to be done for this effect to be achieved (also, both the blue and the green widgets are of dynamic height)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              height: 300,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          )),
          Container(
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.green,
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Mess around with the blue containers height to get scrolling to work. The key Widget here is [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) as it makes it's child height be the greatest room available inside the column. It will take up the rest of the space that the green container is not using

Id highly recommend reading [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-the-advanced-layout-rule-even-beginners-must-know-edc9516d1a2) to better understand how widgets are laid out in Flutter.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I want to make the *entire* page scrollable, not only the content.

Comment: Another problem is that both the content and the footer should be able to have a dynamic height

Comment: Have you tried using a Stack?

Answer (score 0):

use `bottomNavigationBar` parameter in you Scaffold for fixed widget to bottom screen